# taking input of large no in c

Tags: c, long-integer

Our initial numbers are 1,2 ,3 ,4 , and 5 . We can calculate the following sums using four of the five integers:

If we sum everything except 1 , our sum is . 2+3+4+5;

and same as rest

As you can see, the minimal sum is min and the maximal sum is max. Thus, we print these minimal and maximal sums as two space-separated integers on a new line.

Hints: Beware of integer overflow! Use 64-bit Integer.

This is my problem but it failed to test some values....i think it is the datatype issut but i have taken the longest no i can

Fails for this input:
769082435 210437958 673982045 375809214 380564127

Help me out here.

```
int main()
{
     int n=5;
    long long  unsigned int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

       long long  unsigned int ar[n],min=0,max=0,sum=0;


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    scanf("%lld",&arr[i]);
    }


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum= arr[i]+sum;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

    ar[i] = sum -arr[i];

    }




    for(int i=0; i<n ;i++)
    {
            min=ar[0];

        if(min> ar[i])
           min =ar[i];

    }

     for(int i=0; i<n ;i++)
    {
            max=ar[0];

        if(max< ar[i])
           max =ar[i];

    }

    printf("%lld %lld",min,max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `long long  unsigned int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);` that's not allocating enough memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocated memory for proper type of variable namely `unsigned long long` not `int`. To get rid of these silly mistakes you can use this simple way -

```
long long  unsigned int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * n);
```

Here you don't have to worry about the type of what is being pointed to. It is determined without you explicitly mentioning it.

Inside the for loop you are setting `min` to `ar[0]` again and again. This is not right. Do it exactly once before entering loop. Same goes with `max` variable too. The for loop will be (similarly for the `max` variable also)

```
unsigned long long min =ar[0];
for(int i=0; i<n ;i++)
{
    if(min > ar[i])
       min = ar[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating the wrong number of bytes:

```
long long  unsigned int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

you want to create an array of `long long unsigned int`, but you only allocate
space for `n` `ints`. The correct `malloc` call would be

```
long long  unsigned int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);
```

As for the other error, [coderredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3796113/coderredoc)'s answer tell you more about these, no point in repeating them here.